# QT/QT-Designer Question: auto-resizing widget

Tags: qt

Using  QT-Designer, I put a container widget on my window. I'd like it to snap to the edges of the window and cover the entire client area. The window is resizeable.

Do I have to subscribe to resize events and manually change the size of the child widget? or is there some mechanism I can use  that does that automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just select the main window widget in the form editor and tell it to lay out its children horizontally (Ctrl-1) or vertically (Ctrl-2).  They're under the Form menu.

(If you're using Qt *Creator* use Ctrl-1, Ctrl-2 or under the menu in Tools -> Form Editor.)

If you change your mind later you can break the layout and rearrange things.

The "expand to fill the available space" is the general rule in Qt (as per most other toolkits.)  It's probably worth reading up on [QLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html) and [layout management in general](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html).

Comment: not sure I get it. CTRL-H and CTRL-L have no influence, and there is no "TOOLS" on the top menu in QT Designer 4.7.0.

Comment: @Ron M.  Sorry, I was looking at Qt Creator, not Designer - hopefully the updated answer will point you in the right direction now - it's Ctrl-1 and Ctrl-2 instead.

Comment: these options are disabled, regardless of what I select. I was under the impression these were for the horiz or vertical layout of multiple widgets. What i need to do is have ONE widget on the entire area of a window, and automatically adjust with the parent window resize.